# Submitting form with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm completely lost on how to submit a form with Ajax. I'm fairly new to Javascript and hopefully I'm not in over my head.

When I click submit on my form, nothing happens on my page, not in my SQL database where the info should be stored (double checked process form too).

Here's the code if anyone's willing to help:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../process.php",
            type: "post",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="" id="form">

    <span id="input">
        <input  type="text" name="first" maxlength="50" size="30" title="First Name" class="textbox">
        <input  type="text" name="last" maxlength="80" size="30" title="Last Name" class="textbox">
        <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" title="Email" class="textbox">
        <textarea  name="request" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" title="Request"></textarea>
    </span>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">   

</form>
```

Comment: Have you opened your javascript console / developer tools?

Comment: Is the php path correct? How about trying an absolute path for your php script?

Comment: PHP path is correct, works when I put it as the action="..." in the form.

Comment: Any errors in your js console? Can you check that in Chrome Inspector/Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents the page from refreshing
    var $this = $(this); // cache $(this) for later use
    $.ajax({
        url: "../process.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $this.serialize()
    });
});
```

Also could be to do with the `dataType` property. Or various other things.

Answer (score 0):

I use input type button instead submit button. I validate form field when user click button using click event.When validation pass then call ajax.

something like this,

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit">   

jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.submit').click(function(){
    if(validatemyform()){
    //call ajax here
}
});
});
```